# Get the total height of Scroll within UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UICollectionView` that I would like to resize (height) when the content is loaded. The idea is that the height should expand so that all UICollectionView Cells are visible. I was wondering if it was possible to get the "content" size or the scroll height?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easy, a collection view is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you can read its `contentSize` property.

```
CGFloat h = self.collectionView.contentSize.height;
```

The same goes for table views.

Sidenote: I even have done KVO on it once, to get notified when the content size changes.

Answer (score 17):

```
CGFloat height = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;
```

Comment: it works...it's also work when you have a collection view as child view controller. You can get the total content size as per the collection view content.

Comment: That's actually more reliable than the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have a collection view inside a table view cell. To set height of the cell, I need to get height of the collection view. The marked answer was not working properly for me, but this solution is working perfectly fine.

Comment: This is more reliable solution as content height doesn't give appropriate height when added as child view.